# Как создать массив из набора данных в JAVA?

Tags: java

есть некоторые наборы данных (в 1С это бы называлось коллекцией)например

```
1 мерин 25-05-20012
2 аудюха 17-06-2012
3 жигуль 22-06-2012
```

как мне это упаковать в массив (построчно конечно) и как потом его перебрать?

Comment: все зависит от того в каком виде ваша программа получает данные на вход. plain text или считывает с СУБД ?

Comment: читает с СУБД json-строку и парсит в строковые переменные

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать например класс, ну чтобы обращаться к полям надо еще добавить геттеры и сеттеры

```
class Record {

  private int number;
  private String name,date;

  public Record(String token) {
    String[] data = token.split(" ");
    this.number = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
    this.name = data[1];
    this.date = data[2];
  }
}
```

Потом создать

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();
```

добавлять

```
list.add(new Record(inputString));
```

Проходиться по нему

```
for (Record record : list) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Если не усложнять геттерами/сеттерами, то поля класса можно объявить public, а не private.

Если размер массива известен заранее (и предполагается простое манипулирование его содержимым), то вместо ArrayList просто опишите массив объектов Вашего класса.

А вообще, @baralgin1003, для начала прочтите любую книжку по Java.

Comment: > А вообще, @baralgin1003, для начала прочтите любую книжку по Java.
судя по приведеному примеру не одному ему надо читать книжки

Comment: а что с примером? можно конструктивную критику? с удовольствием послушал бы, как не надо и как надо делать
уж книжек (да и не только на книжках учился) я много прочитал

Comment: эти 2 строчки в качестве примера сойдут?

    ArrayList<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();
    List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();

Comment: Я думал, что-то глобальное

Ну да, торопился писал. В реальном проекте так бы не написал
Спасибо за поправку

Comment: В принцыпе, торопится вас никто не заставлял. Кроме того, время для того чтоб написать комментарий у вас есть а значит найдется время чтоб отредактировать ответ.   
+ еще нюанс с самим классом: Record сам по себе обычный java bean, вы же запихнули в него фукнционал который по сути не привязан к отдельному инстансу класса, а значит имеет смысл использовать фабричный метод. 

когда делается code review в 90% случаев можно сказать, что каждая найденная ошибка не существенная. с другой стороны их наличие/отсутствие позволяет судить о вас как о специалисте

Comment: @jmu ну да исправить могу
Даже догадываюсь какую книгу Вы бы мне посоветывали.
На самом деле Вы правы, лучше в следующий раз не надо торопиться. Так что и минус вполне себе заслуженный (фабричный метод использовать не буду в редакции, если автору нужно сам разберется).

К сожалению, я всего лишь пока студент (да еще год недавно проведен в ВС РФ без особой пользы для специальности). Спасибо, прислушаюсь к вашему совету

Comment: Всем спасибо, сам додумался. Как оказалось, что сделал почти аналогично, как rasmisha написал) объем данных у меня небольшой, поэтому этого вполне достаточно. Просто сроки кипят, поэтому читать книги нету особого времени, беру куски необходимого функционала из интернета.

Comment: на самом деле данный пример json не распарсит. я бы для этой цели посоветовал http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

Answer (score 0):

Двумерным массивом в данном случае 3 на 3, при помощи цикла for